# I am trying to setup push notifications on heroku using cloud code?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I have a parse server setup in Heroku, while using Parse Cloud Code push notifications are not working?

I've tried the same setup in AWS EC2 instance, and had the same problem.

**main.js**

```
Parse.Cloud.define('pushChannelTest', function(request, response) {
var recipientUser = request.params.user;
var message = request.params.message;
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.equalTo('username', recipientUser);
query.equalTo("deviceType", "android");
Parse.Push.send({
  where: query,      // for sending to a specific channel
  data: message,
  }, { success: function() {
     console.log("#### PUSH OK");
  }, error: function(error) {
     console.log("#### PUSH ERROR" + error.message);
  }, useMasterKey: true});

  response.success('success');
});
```

**Android Code:**

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("recipientUser", editText_push.getText().toString());
        params.put("message", "######");
        ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("pushChannelTest", params, new FunctionCallback<String>() {
            public void done(String success, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // Push sent successfully
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

**Error stacktrace:**

```
04-30 20:12:51.944 19652-21717/com.example.jayaprakashsivagami.water30 V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 42099
04-30 20:12:51.945 19652-21717/com.example.jayaprakashsivagami.water30 V/FA: Connecting to remote service
04-30 20:12:51.956 19652-21717/com.example.jayaprakashsivagami.water30 V/FA: Activity paused, time: 25125308
04-30 20:12:52.003 19652-21717/com.example.jayaprakashsivagami.water30 D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=42099, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=PushActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-6471612216248973172}]
04-30 20:12:52.134 19652-21717/com.example.jayaprakashsivagami.water30 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
04-30 20:12:52.273 19652-21717/com.example.jayaprakashsivagami.water30 D/FA: Connected to remote service
04-30 20:12:52.275 19652-21717/com.example.jayaprakashsivagami.water30 V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
04-30 20:12:57.334 19652-21717/com.example.jayaprakashsivagami.water30 V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
04-30 20:13:05.901 19652-21717/com.example.jayaprakashsivagami.water30 V/FA: Connecting to remote service
04-30 20:13:05.904 19652-21717/com.example.jayaprakashsivagami.water30 V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 25139280
04-30 20:13:05.952 19652-21717/com.example.jayaprakashsivagami.water30 D/FA: Connected to remote service
04-30 20:13:05.962 19652-21717/com.example.jayaprakashsivagami.water30 V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
04-30 20:13:10.968 19652-21717/com.example.jayaprakashsivagami.water30 V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: I've pushed the open-source parse server code + mongodb sandbox

Comment: If you have fixed this issue, please post an answer so that people with similar issues/queries find a solution.

Comment: I missed to add the push config to index.js.(my bad)